# Converting localStorage to Parse.com

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform, marionette, backbone-views

As an exercise to myself for a future app, I'm attempting to convert a modified app from a book that uses localStorage. The converted app will use Parse.com data instead of localStorage.

Long story short, it's not working. I can fetch the collection from Parse.com, but the View won't render it. I don't get any errors, it just does not display the data. After a lot of debugging, I noticed a difference between the array that is returned in the localStorage version and the Parse.com version:

**localStorage:**

```
Array[1]
0: child
[object Object]: (...)
get [object Object]: function () {
set [object Object]: function (newval) {
[object Object],[object Object]: (...)
get [object Object],[object Object]: function () {
set [object Object],[object Object]: function (newval) {
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]: (...)
get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]: function () {
set [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]: function (newval) {
__backboneDebugger__appComponentInfo: window.__backboneAgent.AppComponentInfo
__backboneDebugger__isInstancePatched: true
_byId: Object
_events: Object
initialize: (...)
length: 3
models: (...)
get models: function () {
set models: function (newval) {
sync: function () {
trigger: function (name) {
url: (...)
get url: function () {
set url: function (newval) {
watchers: Object
__proto__: Surrogate
length: 1
__proto__
```

but Parse.com version:

```
Array[1]
0: child
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_callbacks: Object
length: 2
models: Array[2]
0: child
_callbacks: Object
_escapedAttributes: Object
_hasData: true
_hashedJSON: Object
_opSetQueue: Array[1]
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_serverData: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c1"
collection: child
createdAt: Wed Apr 16 2014 20:23:50 GMT-0400 (EDT)
id: "qYM3ORQ6po"
updatedAt: Fri Apr 18 2014 18:21:12 GMT-0400 (EDT)
__proto__: EmptyConstructor
1: child
_callbacks: Object
_escapedAttributes: Object
_hasData: true
_hashedJSON: Object
_opSetQueue: Array[1]
_pending: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
_serverData: Object
_silent: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: child
createdAt: Wed Apr 16 2014 22:10:07 GMT-0400 (EDT)
id: "SpCYqDPZdZ"
updatedAt: Wed Apr 16 2014 22:27:16 GMT-0400 (EDT)
__proto__: EmptyConstructor
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: EmptyConstructor
length: 1
```

localStorage renders properly, but Parse.com doesn't render at all. The correct data is in the Parse.com array... so it's certainly retrieving it from Parse.com. But, as you can see, the data is formatted very differently.

I suspect that's where my problem lies.

The main difference between the code is "Backbone.model" was changed to "Parse.Object"... and "Backbone.Collection" changed to "Parse.Collection". I then removed the "url" parameter from the Parse.Collection and specified the model:

**localStorage**

```
Entities.CharacterCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "characters",
    model: Entities.Character
  });
```

**Parse.com:**

```
Entities.CharacterCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
   model: Entities.Character
  });
```

I am really at a loss here. I have the feeling the problem is simple, but I'm just missing it.
I'm using the Parse.com JavaScript API, and my code using Marionette as well.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I started over from scratch with a simpler project, yet I'm still having the problem. I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I'll ask in a different way:
When I retrieve a collection of Parse objects, is there anything I need to do to that data before I can use underscore.js to help me view it? I can see the data in console.log, but it's deeply nested. I think the data I'm receiving from the collection simply won't work with the View:   
    `render: function() {
    var html = this.template();
    this.$el.html(html);
    this.collection.each(this.renderOne, this);

    return this;`

Thks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with parse.com but aren't you able to retrieve the data from parse.com and stucture it as such that you can use it to fill a backbone.collection?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes, and that is part of what I'm struggling with: how do I restructure the data appropriately?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a jsfiddle which retrieves some data from parse.com? Then we can have a look and try to use it with backbone.

Comment: If i created a jsfiddle, I'd be giving everyone access to my API key and my data, right?

Comment: If that's the case, you shouldn't do that. However, you can provide the server response as an example.